# Inheritance and contract creation

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, remix

If I modularise a contract into two contracts, and inherit one of them instead using a monolithic approach, will the deployment costs be larger with two contracts or is the cost the same as with the monolithic approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try.

**Monolithic**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract A {
    function doIt() public {
    }
    function doOther(uint value5) public {
    }
}
```

39293 gas

**Inheritance**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract A2 {
    function doIt() public {
    }
}

contract B2 is A2 {
    function doOther(uint value5) public {
    }
}
```

39293 gas when deploying contract B2.

This is because in reality the compiler flattens the contracts before compiling them. So the end result will actually look like contract `A` in both cases.